# Check the spring boot generated jar

Tags: spring-boot, security

I would like to find a way to ensure that when a spring boot app starts, the jar is the one that I compiled.
The goal is for security issues, I distribute an app, and I'd like to have a way to ensure no one modified it (during deploy, or just before it starts)

What would be the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Spring boot itself doesn't handle that.

You may generate a "hash" of the jar (sha1 for example). During the build and store it somewhere. At this point you're sure that this is your jar because you build it right now, this will be a source of truth.

Later on, when you distribute the jar, before starting it you re-generate the hash of the jar with the same algorithm from the bash script or something and compare with the hash that you've generated during the build. If they're the same - its the same jar, otherwise it won't pass the security test.

Comment: Thanks, 
that was what I was afraid of, no embedded existing option.
Regarding the hash, I thought of it, but I will have to store it somewhere outside the executable (otherwise, the hash will change the hash ...)

I'll keep thinking what I can come up with